# Rails 3 - button_to update same page with controller#method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my project I have the following form_tag to select a Site

```
<%= form_tag({:controller => "hvacs", :action => "index"}, :method => "get") do %>

  <div class="field">
        <%= select :p, :site_sel, @user_sites.map{|s| [s.name, s.id]} %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= submit_tag("Select site") %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This form_tag updates the index page through calling its method in the controller again.

I have the following button_to

```
 <td><%= button_to 'Select', {:controller => "hvacs", :action => "select"}, :method => "get" %></td>
```

I would like to achieve a similar update with this as above rather than redirect to a new page with "select_path" etc, but the above does not seem to work.

How can I achieve this? Cheers!

Comment: trying to understand what you're getting at -- so when someone submits the form, you want them to be redirected to another page, but when someone uses the button, they should stay on the same page?

Comment: Can you be more specific about "does not work"?

Comment: @kclair - Not quite, the form actually keeps the user on the same page, this is the same result I am looking for from the button_to. Maybe the button_to should refer to :action => "review", as review is the page I want to stay on. I tried but got an exception when passing the required parameters: exception >review.html.erb:53: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting tASSOC
... "hvacs", :action => "review"}, :method => "get" );@output_b...    Apologies, my syntax is pretty bad :P

Comment: @EdJones - Sorry ed. My button_to goes to the 'select' page from the 'review' page. I would like to update the review page instead of navigating to a new one. I also need to pass the parameters required by 'review', but cannot see how to do it.

Comment: You really need to explain more. Expected parameters for review: are they fixed? Are they user-input? What is the action `select` supposed to do? What is the action `review` supposed to do? The form you show: is that the `select` action? Why does a form submit to the `index` action with a `:get` ???????

Comment: Apologies for the lack of context, see my answer below for what worked. On a side notes, the form submits with a :get as it posts otherwise. Is bad practice to change as such?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution worked. Apologies if I was not so clear on what I was looking for.

```
<%= button_to 'Select',  review_hvacs_path(:h => hvac, :a => params[:a], :s => params[:s]) %>
```

I was trying to pass parameters with the button, while staying on the review page.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this looked so much like my AJAX problem, I tried to make it one!

I think all you need is a simple render statement in your select action

```
render :index
```

or
    render :action => 'index'

But see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-redirect_to for more.